# Using ediff with C-x s (save-some-buffers) in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, diff, emacs-ediff

<kbd>C-x s</kbd> uses `diff` to show changes. How can I use `ediff` instead?

Answer (score 3):

I can see a couple of approaches to doing this. The first is to replace the `save-some-buffers-action-alist` variable with modified code, which is more straightforward. The second is to advise `save-some-buffers` and redefine the functions called by those actions, but that's a bit trickier.

I tried it both ways, and I think this is the best option:

```
;; Use ediff instead of diff in `save-some-buffers'
(eval-after-load "files"
  '(progn
     (setcdr (assq ?d save-some-buffers-action-alist)
             `(,(lambda (buf)
                  (if (null (buffer-file-name buf))
                      (message "Not applicable: no file")
                    (add-hook 'ediff-after-quit-hook-internal
                              'my-save-some-buffers-with-ediff-quit t)
                    (save-excursion
                      (set-buffer buf)
                      (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
                        (ediff-current-file)
                        (recursive-edit))))
                  ;; Return nil to ask about BUF again.
                  nil)
               ,(purecopy "view changes in this buffer")))

     (defun my-save-some-buffers-with-ediff-quit ()
       "Remove ourselves from the ediff quit hook, and
return to the save-some-buffers minibuffer prompt."
       (remove-hook 'ediff-after-quit-hook-internal
                    'my-save-some-buffers-with-ediff-quit)
       (exit-recursive-edit))))
```

My attempt at using advice is flawed (it breaks the <kbd>C-r</kbd> behaviour which also calls `view-buffer`, which caused me to reconsider using advice for this purpose), but FWIW:

```
(defadvice save-some-buffers (around my-save-some-buffers-with-ediff)
  "Use ediff instead of diff."
  (require 'cl)
  (flet ((view-buffer (&rest) nil)
         (diff-buffer-with-file
          (buf)
          (add-hook 'ediff-after-quit-hook-internal
                    'my-save-some-buffers-with-ediff-quit t)
          (save-excursion
            (set-buffer buf)
            (ediff-current-file))))
    (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
      ad-do-it)))
(ad-activate 'save-some-buffers)

(defun my-save-some-buffers-with-ediff-quit ()
  "Remove ourselves from the ediff quit hook, and
    return to the save-some-buffers minibuffer prompt."
  (remove-hook 'ediff-after-quit-hook-internal
               'my-save-some-buffers-with-ediff-quit)
  (exit-recursive-edit))
```

Comment: I changed my mind, and elected to update the `save-some-buffers-action-alist` directly. I've edited this answer accordingly, and have improved the code so that I am only changing the action associated with the "d" key.

Comment: p.s. On my windows box with cygwin, the first time I use this I get a "cygwin warning: MS-DOS style path detected" error in an \*ediff-errors\* buffer, but all subsequent uses work as expected. I am presuming I simply have an issue with my cygwin integration to sort out, and that this issue (or anything similar) does not arise in general.

Comment: This answer is great: (1) It answers the question, (2) it elabortes a bit on different solution paths and  (3) it has the appropriate, brief, but pretty sophisticated code. And it works! :-) I wish I could make it the accepted answer...

Answer (score 1):

The variable `diff-command` is customizable, says the documentation.  However, remember that it points to an external program, and not an elisp function.  `ediff` is an elisp function that is in ediff.el.  You might have to edit diff.el to `(require 'ediff)` and then tweak here and there in diff.el to see that you break nothing else.